# Inserting a date automatically

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone show me how I would add a date automatically upon submit to this page? The DB id is "table1" and the feild id is "date".

My code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "Submit")
{
    for ($count = 1; $count <= 9; $count++)
    {
        $fields[$count] = "";
        if (isset($_POST["field" . $count . ""]))
        {
            $fields[$count] = trim($_POST["field" . $count . ""]);
            //echo $fields[$count] . "<br />";
        }
    }

    $con = mysql_connect("local", "user", "pass");
    mysql_select_db("DB", $con);

    $carriername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['carriername']);
    $fromzip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fromzip']);
    $tozip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tozip']);
    $typeofequipment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['typeofequipment']);
    $weight = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['weight']);
    $length = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['length']);
    $paymentamount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['paymentamount']);
    $contactperson = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactperson']);
    $loadtype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loadtype']);

    $insert = "INSERT INTO table1 (`carriername` ,`fromzip` ,`tozip` ,`typeofequipment` ,`weight` ,`length` ,`paymentamount` ,`contactperson` ,`loadtype`) VALUES('$carriername' ,'$fromzip' ,'$tozip' ,'$typeofequipment' ,'$weight' ,'$length' ,'$paymentamount' ,'$contactperson' ,'$loadtype');";
    mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

    $select = "SELECT `carriername` ,`fromzip` ,`tozip` ,`typeofequipment` ,`weight` ,`length` ,`paymentamount` ,`contactperson` ,`loadtype` FROM `table1` ORDER BY `paymentamount` DESC;";
    $result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
</script>
<style ="text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div
 style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 16px 20px 20px; width: 400px; background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216); text-align: center; float: left;">
<form action="" method="post";">
  <div
  style="margin: 8px auto auto; width: 300px; font-family: arial; text-align: left;"><br>
  <table style="font-weight: normal; width: 100%; font-size: 12px;"
 border="1" bordercolor="#929087" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
   <table
 style="font-weight: normal; width: 100%; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;"
 border="1" bordercolor="#929087" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 10%;">Carrier:</td><td>
 <?php  

$con = mysql_connect("local", "user", "pass");
    mysql_select_db("DB", $con);

$query=("SELECT * FROM table2"); 

$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Unable to Make the Query:" . mysql_error() ); 
echo "<select name=carriername>";   

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){  

echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$row['carriername'].">".$row['carriername']."</OPTION>"; 
} 

echo "</select>";  


?>
              </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Pick Zip:</td><td> <input id="fromzip" name="fromzip" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Drop Zip:</td><td> <input id="tozip" name="tozip" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Load Type:</td><td> <input id="loadtype" name="loadtype" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="width: 35%;">Rate:</td><td> <input id="paymentamount" name="paymentamount" maxlength="50"
 style="width: 100%;" type="text">
        </tr>
          </tbody>
  </table>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><input name="submit" value="Submit"
 class="submit" type="submit"></p>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: -20px;">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Mysql, the field type and id is "date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are updating your table anyway, you can do something as simple as using `NOW()`.  An example of this would be:

```
UPDATE table1 SET date=NOW()
```

Make sure your field `date` is type `DATETIME` if you go this route.  You can also use `TIMESTAMP` to update the field whenever the entry is edited.  To create this, just create a column and set the data type to TIMESTAMP:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    last_edited TIMESTAMP 0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

This will create a table (test) and one column (last_edited) and set the default value to `0`.  Whenever this record is edited in any fashion, the column last_edited will be updated with the time and date.

Check out this link for a little more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING. Can you give me an idea on how to put the Update code in?

Comment: Well it doesn't look like the `INSERT` statement you are using has a 'date' column.  Once you create your 'date' column (type `DATETIME`), you can insert `NOW()` just like you insert other data.  You would use `INSERT INTO table1('carriername','fromzip','tozip', ... ...,'date') VALUES('$carriername','$fromzip','$tozip', ... ...,NOW())` (the ... ... representing all of the other data you are putting in to the table)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) function in your query like so:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (carriername, ..., CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

if your field is of type `TIMESTAMP`

If it's of type `DATE`, you could use `NOW()`.

You could also just configure your table to have a default value for the field (being `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and leave it blank when inserting:

```
CREATE TABLE  `database`.`test` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

If you want to do it in PHP, insert/format your date as such:
`date("m/d/y g:i A");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reference to the column `date` in your insert into table1. If you want to insert the current date, set the insert value to NOW().

Comment: can you give me an example using my insert?

Comment: $insert = "INSERT INTO table1 (`carriername` ,`fromzip` ,`tozip` ,`typeofequipment` ,`weight` ,`length` ,`paymentamount` ,`contactperson` ,`loadtype` ,'date') VALUES('$carriername' ,'$fromzip' ,'$tozip' ,'$typeofequipment' ,'$weight' ,'$length' ,'$paymentamount' ,'$contactperson' ,'$loadtype' ,'now()');";
Like this?

Comment: `insert into table1(...,now());`

Comment: don't put the ticks around now(). NOW() is a mysql function that will evaluate to the current date and time.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Set your date column as DATETIME in phpMyAdmin and set it's default value as 'CURRENT TIMESTAMP', by doing this, whenever a row is inserted the date gets the current time value and saved with the row automatically, no need to make the value for date column on each insert in this way...

Comment: You the closest I want. But I get this when I try to save.

Comment: SQL query: 

ALTER TABLE `Carriers` CHANGE `date` `date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 

MySQL said:  

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'date'

Comment: made the column a timestamp and it worked

Comment: If I dont want the clock time to show just the date is there a simple tweek?